# Ouster of all J*** in California near!

Tags: word-meaning

A headline in a 1942 issue of the San Francisco Examiner read: “**Ouster of all Japs in California near!**” Then, on Feb. 19, 1942, President Roosevelt signed Executive Order 9066, which allowed local military commanders to “prescribe military areas” from which “any of all persons may be excluded.”

[Source](https://www.liberationnews.org/racist-internment-japanese-americans/#:%7E:text=A%20headline%20in%20a%201942%20issue%20of%20the,which%20%E2%80%9Cany%20of%20all%20persons%20may%20be%20excluded.%E2%80%9D)

Does "near" here mean "(draws) near"? Is it an adjective? Or a verb?

Comment: It is an adverb. This is in headlinese, which tends to omit short words: in this case "is".

Comment: to be near: to be approaching in time,

Comment: What @ColinFine said. But I'd have expected ***Ousting*** rather than ***Ouster*** in such a context. I don't know if the extremely uncommon derived noun "ouster" (one who ousts) is supposed to refer to Roosevelt or not - but if it does, I can't see what "[draws] near" is supposed to mean. The headline only makes sense if we assume the first word refers to the impending expulsion of Japanese from California.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: "Ouster: 2. Dismissal or expulsion from a position; (more generally) removal from a place or situation. Now chiefly in extended use. Now chiefly U.S." -OED

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I don't think of [**ouster**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ouster) as an extremely uncommon word at all, at least in AmE.  It does not refer to a person, it refers to an action and is a synonym of "expulsion".  [Here is](https://www.usatoday.com/in-depth/news/politics/2021/06/10/israel-keep-us-evangelical-christian-support-without-netanyahu/7600384002/) an example of **ouster** used in a headline just two hours ago.

Comment: okay, okay! I get the message! It's an American newspaper featuring an American usage! It still looks odd to me.

Comment: The word "near" there is a predicate adjective. The headlinese has omitted the linking verb "is". So, "Ouster of X is near."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an adjective. It modifies the noun “ouster.” It means what you suggested in the question - it is happening soon.

Headlines often use a sort of abbreviated form of English that doesn’t match normal sentence structure. That is why there is no verb. Native speakers understand “near” in this case to mean “(is) near.”